# How do I target which ads I'd like to refresh with GPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-dfp

I'm defining all my adSlots in the header of my page and in the JavaScript I want to refresh "some" of those adSlots based on their location on the page.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  slot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/1234/example', [[728, 90], 'gpt-divId1')
    .addService(googletag.pubads());
  slot2 = googletag.defineSlot('/1234/example', [[300, 250], 'gpt-divId2')
    .addService(googletag.pubads());
  slot3 = googletag.defineSlot('/1234/example', [[300, 250], 'gpt-divId3')
    .addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
googletag.enableServices();
```

I'm then putting the name of that defined slot into a `data-gpt-slot` attribute of each div, as such: `<div attr="slot1" id="gpt-divId1">`.

In a separate JavaScript, I'm trying to run through my DOM, getting a list of all the `data-gpt-slot` values within a certain area and adding them to the `googletag.pubads().refresh();`

If I manually call `googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1,slot2])`, those ads will refresh, but if I try to build that string through jQuery, it's not playing.

```
  var gptdivs = [];
  $('.myContainer .gpt-holder').each(function(){
    gptdivs.push($(this).attr('data-gpt-slot'));
  });
  googletag.pubads().refresh([gptdivs]);
```

I suspect I'm missing something about the properties of `$(this).attr('data-gpt-slot')` and `slot1`, `slot2`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use the refresh method incorrectly. It takes the actual ad unit instance as an argument not just the name of it as a string.

Try this instead:

```
var adunits = {};

adunits['slot1'] = googletag.defineSlot('/1234/example', [[728, 90], 'gpt-divId1').addService(googletag.pubads());
adunits['slot2'] = googletag.defineSlot('/1234/example', [[300, 250], 'gpt-divId2').addService(googletag.pubads());
adunits['slot3'] = googletag.defineSlot('/1234/example', [[300, 250], 'gpt-divId3').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

And then your code to refresh the adunits becomes:

```
var gptdivs = [];
$('.myContainer .gpt-holder').each(function(){
    gptdivs.push(adunits[$(this).attr('data-gpt-slot')]);
});
googletag.pubads().refresh(gptdivs);
```

Comment: I had to change adunits to global since my refresh code is in a separate file, but right on the money - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a deep array here, causing your issue

```
refresh([gptdivs])
```

Just try

```
refresh(gptdivs)
```